# Global line breaks for LaTeX documents

Tags: line-breaking

I have a problem with line breaking. I wrote a tool to generate reports that contain long lines e.g. URLs or paths. In my resulting PDF these lines should be wrapped. Additionally, the wrapping should be done automatically. I know that I am able to insert manual wrapping. But I need a **global** approach (no functions surrounding the long lines) like a rule or a global enforcing of word wrapping if the line ends.

I already tried `\sloppy` and the `microtype` package. But with no success.

To illustrate my problem I made a simple LaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{path}

\begin{document}

\specialpathdelimiterstrue

AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash AAAA\textbackslash 

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

http://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{document}
```

All three lines should be wrapped at the end of the line/page width.

Is there even a solution for this? I already searched days for a solution..

Comment: I think the OP's “no functions surrounding the long lines” excludes the answers that currently exist on that question...

Comment: is it really impossible for you to mark url as `\url{http://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}` ?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you don't want to use a macro for each line because your lines are generated automatically. But since you may use `\sloppy`, an environment surrounding all your lines might be ok.

Then a possible idea is to scan the content of the environment and add discretionary breaks between characters.

The code below defines an environment `wraplines` inside which all lines are wrapped at end of line.

```
\begin{wraplines}
% text
\end{wraplines}
```

The environment takes an optional hyphenation character which may actually be arbitrary restricted horizontal mode material: `-`, `$\rightarrow$`, ...

```
\begin{wraplines}[-]
% text
\end{wraplines}
```

The code assumes that only text occurs inside the environment. However the text may contain several paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{wraplines}[1][]{%
  % encapsulate hyphenation character in a \hbox so that
  % it may be arbitrary restricted horizontal mode material e.g $\rightarrow$
  \def\@wrapdiscr{\discretionary{\hbox{#1}}{}{}}%
  \@wraplines
}{}
\newcommand\@wraplines{%
  \@ifnextchar\end\relax{%
    \@ifnextchar\par{%
      \par\expandafter\@wraplines\@gobble
    }%
    \@wraplines@aux
  }%
}
\def\@wraplines@aux#1 {\x@wraplines@aux#1\@nnil}
\newcommand*\x@wraplines@aux[1]{#1\y@wraplines@aux}
\newcommand*\y@wraplines@aux[1]{%
  \ifx#1\@nnil
    \space
    \expandafter\@wraplines
  \else
    \@wrapdiscr#1%
    \expandafter\y@wraplines@aux
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{wraplines}
\end{wraplines}

\noindent\verb|\begin{wraplines} ... \end{wraplines}|

\begin{wraplines}
Xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{wraplines}

\bigskip

\noindent\verb|\begin{wraplines}[-] ... \end{wraplines}|

\begin{wraplines}[-]
Xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{wraplines}

\bigskip

\noindent\verb|\begin{wraplines}[$\rightarrow$] ... \end{wraplines}|

\begin{wraplines}[$\rightarrow$]
Xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{wraplines}

\end{document}
```

[image: wrap.png]