# Umlauts in wraplines environment breaks the document

Tags: line-breaking

Thanks to the user Eric Domenjoud from my previous post [Global line breaks for LaTeX documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476751/global-line-breaks-for-latex-documents) I am able to break text in my auto-generated reports. See the example form Eric below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{wraplines}[1][]{%
  % encapsulate hyphenation character in a \hbox so that
  % it may be arbitrary restricted horizontal mode material e.g $\rightarrow$
  \def\@wrapdiscr{\discretionary{\hbox{#1}}{}{}}%
  \@wraplines
}{}
\newcommand\@wraplines{%
  \@ifnextchar\end\relax{%
    \@ifnextchar\par{%
      \par\expandafter\@wraplines\@gobble
    }%
    \@wraplines@aux
  }%
}
\def\@wraplines@aux#1 {\x@wraplines@aux#1\@nnil}
\newcommand*\x@wraplines@aux[1]{#1\y@wraplines@aux}
\newcommand*\y@wraplines@aux[1]{%
  \ifx#1\@nnil
    \space
    \expandafter\@wraplines
  \else
    \@wrapdiscr#1%
    \expandafter\y@wraplines@aux
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{wraplines}
\end{wraplines}

\noindent\verb|\begin{wraplines} ... \end{wraplines}|

\begin{wraplines}
Xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{wraplines}

\bigskip

\noindent\verb|\begin{wraplines}[-] ... \end{wraplines}|

\begin{wraplines}[-]
Xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{wraplines}

\bigskip

\noindent\verb|\begin{wraplines}[$\rightarrow$] ... \end{wraplines}|

\begin{wraplines}[$\rightarrow$]
Xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{wraplines}

\end{document}
```

The solution is very good and nearly solves my problem (many thanks to Eric)! But there is one little problem: umlauts...

With the following LaTeX:

```
\begin{wraplines}
äüö
\end{wraplines}
```

I get this error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\y@wraplines@aux (U+67B)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.36   äüö
```

The general use of umlauts in my document is no problem (I use the necessary headers). Only in the `wraplines` environment the conversion to the PDF breaks.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Comment: It will only work with an unicode engine (xelatex or lualatex). The wraplines code can't handle multibytes char and commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it wouldn't take much to extend it, I may post in a bit